# pgfplots spline and colorseries do not work

Tags: pgfplots

I want to create a plot with predefined colors and have the points connected by a spline curve.

Both things do not happen. The color series is not applied (all lines are black) and a spline is not applied to the curve.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.patchplots}

\definecolor{colorseriesRGB1}{RGB}{0,     0, 192}
\definecolor{colorseriesRGB2}{RGB}{192,   0,   0}
\definecolor{colorseriesRGB3}{RGB}{0  , 128,   0}
\definecolor{colorseriesRGB4}{RGB}{192,   0, 192}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{colorseries-rgb}{
  {colorseriesRGB1},
  {colorseriesRGB2},
  {colorseriesRGB3},
  {colorseriesRGB4},
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width=0.8\textwidth, height=0.6\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[cycle list name=colorseries-rgb]
\addplot[samples = 10,patch type=quadratic spline] {x^2 - x +4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT:

My original code is using a datatable. If I add the options `mesh,patch,patch type=quadratic spline` then the plot looks completely wrong

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale only axis,
             every axis plot/.append 
               style={line width=1.5pt},
             mark=none,
             style=solid,
             enlargelimits=false, ymax = 3.5,
             cycle list name=colorseries-office,
             % smooth,
             mesh,patch,patch type=quadratic spline
             ]
  %  column with header  "y1"
  \addplot+   table[x=x1,y=y1]  from  \datatable;
  \addplot+   table[x=x1,y=y2]  from  \datatable;
  \addplot+   table[x=x1,y=y3]  from  \datatable;
  \addplot+   table[x=x1,y=y4]  from  \datatable;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

However the option `smooth`, although I have no idea what it really does looks like what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no optional arguments, then simply using

```
\addplot {x^2 - x +4};
```

will inherit the correct styles that you have specified. However, if you wish to override some of the arguments *but keep the other aspects* (as you have done in your code), then you have to use `\addplot+[...`

```
\addplot+[samples = 10] {x^2 - x +4};
```

which tells `pgfplots` to use the styles specified in `cyclelist`, but change the options that you have specified.

See Section 4.6.7 for more examples.

With regards to the `quadratic spline`, referencing Section 5.6.1,

> The quadratic spline is actually nothing but piecewise Lagrangian
>   interpolation with quadratic polynomials: it expects three points in
>   the sequence ‘(left end), (right end), (middle)’ and interpolates
>   these three points with a quadratic polynomial.

As such, for your example you can use something like

```
% left, right, middle
\addplot+[patch,mesh,patch type=quadratic spline]coordinates{(-5,33)(5,23)(0,3)};
```

It seems like you're currently trying to feed a function in to help find the coordinates- I don't know how to do this, but perhaps one of the gurus on this site will.

Comment: The + gives me a blue line, but the lines still appear not as a curve without edges, so no spline is applied.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech see my edit

Comment: What I was looking for seems to be the option `smooth`, but then I do not understand the meaning of `patch` at all. If I also add the option `patch`, then my line is dashed and with variing colors in a  line.

Comment: @cmhughes Add `smooth`?

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech AFAIK `smooth` and `patch` are for situations where you have `coordinates`; if you have the formula, why not just increase `samples`?

Comment: @cmhuges The function was just for demonstration. I added the result of my real life code, but without the dataset. I have no coordinates, but I assume that my data from a table is equivalent.